# If $n$ is an odd positive integer, then $2^{n!} − 1$ is divisible by $n$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

Prove that if $n$ is an odd positive integer, then $2^{n!} − 1$ is divisible by $n$.

Progress so far: Let $n=2k+1$. The desired result becomes $2^{(2k+1)!} − 1$
By Euler's totient function theorem, we have that

$2^{\phi(2k+1)}=1\mod(2k+1).$ I cannot seem to rigorously prove that this is true also for $(2k+1)!.$

Comment: Well...$\varphi(n)<n$, clearly.  Hence $\varphi(n) \,|\,n!$.

Comment: The above hint should be sufficient to write an answer. If you are convinced, then please attempt an answer below.

Comment: Is this the case because now we have that $2^{k\phi(n)}=1\mod(n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^rp_i^{e_i}$, then $\;\varphi(n)=\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{e_i-1}(p_i - 1)\;$ is clearly a divisor of $n!$ since each of its factors is less than $n$ and they're all distinct, so 
$$2^{n!}=\bigl(2^{\varphi(n)} \bigr)^{\tfrac{n!}{\varphi(n)}}\equiv 1\mod n$$
by *Euler's theorem*.